# Can you universally specify using a proper name that is already present in the premise?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

i was working on one of the problems in Patrick Suppes' An Introduction to logic, and it asks to show whether "Ptah is an egyptian god. Ptah is the father of all egytpian gods. Therefore Ptah is the father of himself." is a valid argument or not. By universally specifying "if x is an egyptian god, then ptah is the father of x" using "ptah" i get "if ptah is an egyptian god, then ptah is the father of ptah" and combining this with the first premise, i can derive "Ptah is the father of ptah". But it doesnt sound right to me so im wondering if my universal specification was a valid move.

Comment: If Ptah is the father of all egytpian gods and "Ptah is an egyptian god, then Path **must** be father of himself. In logic "all" means **all**.

Comment: Yes, it is valid. The reason it does not "feel" right is because normal speech would implicitly exclude Ptah himself from the claim "Ptah is the father of all Egytpian gods". But in logic such exclusions need to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: More abstractly, ∃!p,∃G,F∀x (Gx → Fx, Gp) → Fp